# Differences between IETF standard JSON schema and Avro schema

Tags: java, json, avro, jsonschema, avro4s

Please help me understand the differences between IETF standard JSON schema and Avro schema. I google a lot but couldn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 3):

The key difference is this:

- IETF JSON schemas are schemas *for* JSON values; i.e. JSON objects and JSON arrays
- Avro schemas are schemas *for* Avro values.

Both JSON schemas and Avro schemas are *expressed* in JSON.  But the type systems that they describe are different.  For example, Avro has 6 kinds of complex types compared to JSON's 2 kinds.

---

A second difference is that IETF JSON schemas venture into areas such as validation (of values), schemas referencing other schemas and so forth.  Thus, you could say that JSON schemas have a broader *scope* than Avro schemas.  (But you don't have to make use of this if it isn't relevant to your use-cases.)

Comment: Since Avro schemas are expressed in JSON, one can have a JSON Schema to describe the structure of an Avro schema. It's schemas all the way down :)

Comment: I assume that you meant to say *"one can have a JSON Schema to describe the structure of **all Avro schemas**"*.

Comment: @Ether Avro also has IDL schema definitions

Comment: @Ether - Eventually someone figures out how model schemas in themselves :-)